# I have a problem with submit button on mvc web app

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

My button looks like this:

```
       <button type="submit" id="click" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Click to submit labels</button>
```

So on this app works about 5 people in the same time, so what is the problem here, on click button values are saving to the report, but when two of them click at the same time value is duplicated,

**sample**: first one click , value save 13, second one click value saved as 14, but if they are click in same time value will be:

first one - 13,

second one - 13.

Can i resolve this with simple script or i need to correct something in controller.

This is what have i tried:

```
<script>
                    function DisplayProgressMessage(ctl, msg) {
                        $(ctl).prop("disabled", true);
                        $(ctl).text(msg);
                        return true;
                    }
                </script>
```

Comment: To solve the issue we need to see more than the button. We will need to see the form, any js involved, and the code in your controller to handle the click.

Comment: I use this code

<script>
                        function DisplayProgressMessage(ctl, msg) {
                            $(ctl).prop("disabled", true);
                            $(ctl).text(msg);
                            return true;
                        }
                    </script>

, That is what have i tried and it work when i click but i think that this will not work when i update app on server.

Comment: Can you edit your original post and format as code please. Much easier to read and helpful for others looking to this question in the future